# wxPython: weird visual artifacts when using custom controls with a notebook control

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm having weird visual artifacts when I use a custom control with a notebook control. I managed to get the bug isolated to a small program.

I am using Python 2.7 and wxPython, not having made the switch to Python 3 yet. I have a custom control that draws "A's." I use a vertical Box sizer and draw two A's, and then I draw a static text label. The second A is initially a black box, which is the bug. If I move the window off screen and back on, it becomes a second A. Oddly enough this only happens if there are two tabs, if I remove the two lines dealing with tab2, the bug goes away.

Also, I based my custom control off of the following link. This link used a checkbox custom control and had the same issue that my custom control had:
https://wiki.wxpython.org/CreatingCustomControls

Any help is appreciated!

```
import wx

class MyControl(wx.PyControl):
    def __init__(self, parent, size):
        wx.PyControl.__init__(self, parent, style=wx.BORDER_NONE)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND, self.OnEraseBackground)
        self.SetInitialSize(size)

    def OnPaint(self, event):
        dc = wx.BufferedPaintDC(self)
        dc.Clear()
        dc.DrawText("A", 0, 0)

    def OnEraseBackground(self, event):
        pass

class GUI(object):
    def __init__(self):
        app = wx.App(False)
        windowFrame = wx.Frame(None)
        windowFrame.SetSize((300, 300))

        notebook = wx.Notebook(windowFrame)
        tab1 = wx.Panel(notebook)
        tab1Sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        tab1.SetSizer(tab1Sizer)
        notebook.AddPage(tab1, "Tab1")

        tab2 = wx.Panel(notebook)
        notebook.AddPage(tab2, "Tab2")

        myControl1 = MyControl(tab1, size=(20,20))
        tab1Sizer.Add(myControl1)
        myControl2 = MyControl(tab1, size=(20,20))
        tab1Sizer.Add(myControl2)
        label3 = wx.StaticText(tab1, label="Test3")
        tab1Sizer.Add(label3)

        windowFrame.Show()
        app.MainLoop()

def main():
    GUI()

main()
```

Comment: I could reproduce the problem, you should report it as a bug. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/wx-dev

Comment: Sometimes the order of events during program startup are not quite as expected. In this case I think it is due to the initial size event and the refresh that goes with it has already happened because the frame's size was set at the beginning. If you move the `windowFrame.SetSize((300, 300))` line after the notebook and pages have been created then it will probably workaround the issue.

Comment: RobinDunn, that fixed it! Thank you! If you write this comment as an answer, I'll accept it as the best answer